# Django admin reuse header

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to reuse the header of the django admin page in my custom view so I can use the "view site, change password and logout" so I won't have to recode that part.

Is it possible to extend only the header part?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't. Because these are integral part of [**`admin/base.html`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) template. So instead, you can create a new base template and copy the header section from this `admin/base.html`. Like this:

```
{% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}
{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet_rtl %}{% static "admin/css/rtl.css" %}{% endblock %}">{% endif %}
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
{% block responsive %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/responsive.css" %}">
    {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/responsive_rtl.css" %}">{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block blockbots %}<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">{% endblock %}
</head>
{% load i18n %}

<body class="{% if is_popup %}popup {% endif %}{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock %}"
  data-admin-utc-offset="{% now "Z" %}">

<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">

    {% if not is_popup %}
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="branding">
        {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% block usertools %}
        {% if has_permission %}
        <div id="user-tools">
            {% block welcome-msg %}
                {% trans 'Welcome,' %}
                <strong>{% firstof user.get_short_name user.get_username %}</strong>.
            {% endblock %}
            {% block userlinks %}
                {% if site_url %}
                    <a href="{{ site_url }}">{% trans 'View site' %}</a> /
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
                    {% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}
                    {% if docsroot %}
                        <a href="{{ docsroot }}">{% trans 'Documentation' %}</a> /
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.has_usable_password %}
                <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a> /
                {% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- END Header -->
</div>
<!-- END Container -->

</body>
</html>
```